# The name cannot contain any of the following symbols: '[, ], .'.'. for Compose in Azure Logic App

Tags: json, azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-logic-apps

I have below JSON which I need to update inside a logic app

```
{
  "name": "SampleDoc",
  "type": "123",
  "properties": {
    "GP.Test": "M1",
    "MG.Test": "C1"
  }
}
```

[image]

I have used following setProperty syntax: -

```
@setProperty(variables('ResponseBody'),'properties', setProperty(variables('ResponseBody')['properties'], 'test','abc'),
setProperty(variables('ResponseBody')['properties'], 'GP.Test','M2'))
```

My desired JSON output should be

```
{
  "name": "SampleDoc",
  "type": "123",
  "properties": {
    "GP.Test": "M2",
    "MG.Test": "C1"
  }
}
```

But when I am running this, I am getting this error: -

**InvalidTemplate. Unable to process template language expressions in action 'Compose' inputs at line '1' and column '2617': 'The provided property name 'GP.Test' has these invalid characters '.'. The name cannot contain any of the following symbols: '[, ], .'.'.**

Could anyone suggest if we can handle '.' inside compose or any other way for achieving this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes that is correct behavior that is occurring in the logic apps. The reason is that you have used the set property function to set the value of the GP.Test property. When working with the expressions in logic apps, the '.' operator is reserved operator and will be used to access sub properties etc of the expressions, functions etc. Hence you get the error. The solution to this is actually simple, you use the compose action directly without using the set property. Sample screenshot below.
[image]

Or if you want complex transformations, then using the liquid transformations through the integration account is the way to go

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! My scenario is a little bit different as I am getting JSON from the different source system and that is huge. I need to change around 20-25 elements in that. I don't want to use liquid transformation but I am not left with any other option.

Comment: Yes, that is correct, for complex transformations, integration account should be used. You can bypass the need of integration account by creating an azure function which basically does liquid transformation.
but if the reply has satisfactory, could you please mark it as an answer so that other users benefit from it?